# Toggle optional build dependencies and build dependencies using features

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know that Rust allows you to specify optional dependencies in the Cargo.toml manifest, and that you can trigger these dependencies with features. As an example:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "1.0"
bar = "1.0"

[features]
myfeature = ["foo", "bar"]
```

I'm trying to figure if there's a way I can have this apply for build dependencies as well, because I haven't found any documentation indicating that this is possible.

What I want to do is this:

```
[dependencies]
foo = "1.0"

[build-dependencies]
bar = "1.0"

[features]
myfeature = ["foo", "bar"]
```

The context for this is that I want to add the [build-info](https://docs.rs/build-info/0.0.23/build_info/) and [build-info-build](https://docs.rs/build-info-build/0.0.23/build_info_build/) crates to my project, but it adds to the compile time considerably, so I'd like to have a feature and only enable it for release builds.

Comment: Did you try it out? I just tested and it works.

Comment: Yes, my mistake was with the naming of the feature, it can't be identical to one of the crates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this works, my mistake was making the feature name identical to one of the crates, ex: if you have

```yaml
[dependencies]
foo = "1.0"

[build-dependencies]
bar = "1.0"

[features]
foo = ["foo", "bar"]
```

this doesn't seem to work. With a different name it works fine.